# Enable react routing in local disk saved site

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I have entered to my site with browser, then saved it with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>, choosing Webpage Complete option on Google Chrome.

Then, when I'm opened saved html file in browser, my site always redirect me to not found page.

Seems like react-router can't deal with routes from local disk.

My routes.js:

```js
import * as React from 'react';
import { Route } from 'react-router';
import Layout from './containers/Layout';
import Home from './containers/Home';
import Registration from './containers/Registration';
import Cancellation from './containers/Cancellation';
import NotFound from './errorPages/NotFound';

export default <Route component={ Layout }>
    <Route path='/' components={{ body: Home }} />
    <Route path='/registration' components={{ body: Registration }} />
    <Route path='/cancellation' components={{ body: Cancellation }} />
    <Route path='*' components={{body: NotFound}}/>
</Route>;

// Enable Hot Module Replacement (HMR)
if (module.hot) {
    module.hot.accept();
}
```

---

How can I properly deal in such situation, change routes configuration, maybe other variants of saving site, what should I do to save my site and then navigate without any troubles?

Comment: I did not realize and It is not my intention. I did not see any tags when I edited. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to run and configure a server to reroute all requests to your index.html, at which point React Router takes care of all the routing. See here:

https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/docs/guides/Histories.md#browserhistory

The example uses an Express (Node.js) server, the pertinent block is here:

`app.get('*', function (request, response){
  response.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, 'public', 'index.html'))
})`

Although you could also configure another server of your choice if you use something else for your local development.

Comment: That's the key point, to start site without server, only open `mysite.html` in browser and it works. Without react-router, it works perfectly.

Comment: can you clarify your point? you *need* to run a server here for react router to work as you expect

Comment: Could I avoid running a server? That's the main point, working without a server

Comment: what is your limitation preventing you from running one? your production environment will be running a server anyways

Comment: Maybe I need it to give person, who only need to watch this site, without installing bunch of thresh for him. For someone, who need only client-side, also.

Comment: any website that is hosted online will be running a server. whether it's Express or Apache, you'll need to configure it to enable client-side routing

Comment: That's not the current task, hosting it online, current task is give to other person without any server he has. How can I enable client-side routing then?

Comment: you get them to run a server. it could be as simple as installing lamp/mamp and adding a 404 redirect to the .htaccess file